# Return values and variable scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Im having some trouble working out how to correctly return a value within one function and pass it to another. The variable is randomQuestion, and I cant get it to appear in the functions as an integer. The idea is that the same question ID is used in both functions, so for example in the second function I can use it to determine which question was asked, and find the correct answer to match it against the user input.

```
$('#quiz').on('click', beginQuiz);
$('#giveanswer').on('click', nextQuestion);

var randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);

function beginQuiz(randomQuestion) {

    $("#questions tbody tr").remove();
    document.getElementById("questions").deleteTHead();

    //Get the JSON data from our HTML and convert it to a JavaScript object
    //In the real world, this data will likely be retrieved  from the server via an AJAX request
    var questions = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('questions-json').innerHTML);



    console.log(randomQuestion);

    var quizQuestion = questions[randomQuestion];


    var tblRow = '<tr>' + '<td>' + quizQuestion.q_text + '</td>' + '</tr>'
        //Add our table row to the 'questions' <table>
    $(tblRow).appendTo('#questions tbody');

    document.getElementById('answers').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('answerlabel1').innerHTML = quizQuestion.q_options_1;
    document.getElementById('answerlabel2').innerHTML = quizQuestion.q_options_2;
    document.getElementById('answerlabel3').innerHTML = quizQuestion.q_options_3;
    document.getElementById('answerlabel4').innerHTML = quizQuestion.q_options_4;

    return randomQuestion;
}

function nextQuestion(randomQuestion) {

    console.log(randomQuestion);
    //Get the JSON data from our HTML and convert it to a JavaScript object
    //In the real world, this data will likely be retrieved  from the server via an AJAX request
    var questions = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('questions-json').innerHTML);
    var score = 0;
    var playeranswer = $('input:radio[name=answer]:checked').val();
    var correctanswer = questions[randomQuestion].q_correct_option;

    if (playeranswer == questions.q_correct_option) {
        score++
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
    }
}
```

Comment: using different variable name than `randomQuestion` will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the randomQuestion parameter from both your function declarations, since it's a global. As written, both your functions look at their own local raqndomQuestion variable, which is undefined.

Comment: Ah I see, this makes sense. If I wanted to then use the global variable within the second function, however it had changed locally, would it then be overwritten when the function is called along with the global variable?

Comment: If you change the global inside a function, it will get changed globally, so the next function will use the changed value.